# Check if a table value in one model matches a table value in a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This question is kind of hard to ask, but basically, I have a Class model and a User model, each Class table has a token, and so does each User one. After the user submits a sign up form, how would I set the value of the users class_id in the create action? I've tried `<%= f.hidden_field :app_id, :value => App.find_by_token(params[:key]) %>`, but this doesn't work. Sorry for the long and confusing question, will be glad to answer more. Thanks in advance for any answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though you have a "relationship" where a User belongs to a Class and a Class could have many users.  If that is the case then you should use rails Associations to make it easy for yourself.  This would involve adding a 'has_many :users' to your Class model and a 'belongs_to :class' call to your User model.  You would then just use the rails helpers to 'build' the object and save it with the association in the corresponding controllers.

The manual way to do it would be as follows from your controller:

```
def create
  #This would involve you sending the proper class id as a hidden form field with the form field attribute named 'class_id'.  You may need to add 'attr_accessor :class_id' to your User model.
  if user.create(user_params)
    blahblahblah
  else
    sorry blah blah
  end
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :class_id, :etc)
end
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help, even though the question is terrible :D